# Unable to convert image in svg to picture

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, canvas

Hello I am trying to convert svg to png and the basic idea is first convert svg to canvas then save the canvas as png. However the image element inside svg cannot be converted. The code is like:

```js
var testBtn = document.getElementById("testBtn");
 var testSVG = document.getElementById('testSVG');
 var testCanvas = document.getElementById('orgChartCanvas');

 function triggerDownload (imgURI) {
   var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
     view: window,
     bubbles: false,
     cancelable: true
   });

   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.setAttribute('download', 'MY_COOL_IMAGE.png');
   a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
   a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

   a.dispatchEvent(evt);
 }

 testBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('orgChartCanvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(testSVG);
   var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

   var img = new Image();
   var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
   var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

   img.onload = function () {
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,2000,800);
     DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

     var imgURI = canvas
         .toDataURL('image/png')
         .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

     triggerDownload(imgURI);
   };

   img.src = url;
 });
```

```html
<button id = "testBtn">svg to png</button>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id = "testSVG" viewBox="0 0 1367.25 800">
    <g transform="translate(518.625,20)">
        <text style="font-size: xx-large;">Text is converted!</text>
  <image  xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg"></image>
 </g>
</svg>

<canvas id="orgChartCanvas" width="2000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

So is there anyway I can also convert the image in svg to png? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No, nothing in console.